# Split a big file based on a field and add a unique identifier to each file

Tags: python, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a (huge) file like this:

test_file

```
a   b
a   c
a   d
b   a
b   b
a   g
a   j
c   g
```

And I am trying to split it into multiple files based on the first field. However, repeated but not consecutive values should create a new file (i.e. every time the value in field one changes respective to the previous row, a new file should be generated). So, in my previous example, rows:

```
a   g
a   j
```

Should go to a new file different than the one with:

```
a   b
a   c
a   d
```

In the end, I would have 4 files each one representing one of the changes in field one:

a.1

```
a   b
a   c
a   d
```

b.2

```
b   a
b   b
```

a.3

```
a   g
a   j
```

c.4

```
c   g
```

Actually, it would also work if the identifiers are: a.1, b.1, a.2, c.1 or any other kind of suffix. I want to avoid the second subset/group of *a* values to replace/overwrite the previous file generated with the first group of *a* values. I also do not want that all *a* values are appended to the same file.

I know that:

```
awk '{print > $1; close( $1)}' test_file
```

would split using the first column, but it will also append the results to the same file when the key is equal.

To avoid this issue I was thinking of adding another field that really differs. Something like:

test_file

```
1    a  b
1    a  c
1    a  d
2    b  a
2    b  b
3    a  g
3    a  j
4    c  g
```

And then do:

```
 awk '{print > $1"_"$2; close( $1"_"$2) }' test_file
```

But I couldn't really find a way since I think that associative arrays won't work in this case. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you might want this:

```
awk '$1!=prev{ close(out); out="File_"$1"."(++cnt); prev=$1 } { print > out }' test_file
```

but your question isn't totally clear.

Comment: Great! Thanks! :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Awk really is easier, isn't it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
files_count = 1
first_col = None
with open('maria.txt') as maria:
    for line in maria:
        line = line.rstrip()
        columns = line.split()
        if columns[0] == first_col:
            print (line, file=current_out)
        else:
            first_col = columns[0]
            current_out = open(first_col+'.'+str(files_count), 'w')
            files_count+=1
            print (line, file=current_out)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, this could be done using `groupby` as follows:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

with open('huge.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

    for index, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(csv_input, lambda x: x[0]), start=1):
        with open('{}.{}'.format(k, index), 'wb') as f_output:
            csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=' ').writerows(g)
```

---

If you are using Python 3.x:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

with open('huge.txt', 'r', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

    for index, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(csv_input, lambda x: x[0]), start=1):
        with open('{}.{}'.format(k, index), 'w', newline='') as f_output:
            csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=' ').writerows(g)
```